# Increase a div with flex when another is hidden not working on safari

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox

I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleBlue = false;
});
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.row {
  width: 35%;
}
.first {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
.second {
  display: flex;
}
.toggle {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.decrease {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.noWidth {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <span ng-click="toggleBlue = !toggleBlue">TOGGLE BLUE BOX</span>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row first"></div>

    <div class="row second" ng-class="{noWidth: toggleBlue}">
      <div class="toggle" ng-if="!toggleBlue"></div>
      <div class="decrease"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I click on the text **"TOGGLE BLUE BOX"**, it should hide the blue box with `ng-if`, increase the red box to fill it with `flex: 1;` and change the width of the yellow box with `ng-class`. So it should simply toggle the blue box. This works fine on chrome. But when I try it on an iPad in a safari browser, it removes the blue box, but doesn't increase the red one. Also the yellow box is than not in the end it's behind the red one like this:

[image]

My expected result is the same like here in the snippet. How can I fix this on safari? I tried it with `flex: 1 1 auto;` on the class `.first` in case of `flex 1;`, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `width: 35%;` for `.row`?

Comment: @3rdthemagical because I would like to have 35% of grey as width... I think this isn't the error and not really important...

Comment: @Mr_Green I tried to call the script "javascript:alert(navigator.userAgen)" in safari adress but it doesn't work...I don't know I'm on iOS 9.3.3 perhaps this helps, safari is a part of the iOS version I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I'm a bit confused regarding your code. You define display flex but then not really use it on all of your child elements. I've corrected this as best as I can understand but let me know if something is off here.

Also, if you're curious why Safari was freaking out, it's basically your css wasn't following proper standards (not defining flex on all children controls).

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleBlue = false;
});
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 25px;
}
.first {
  flex: 1 1 35px;
  background-color: red;
}
.second {
  flex: 1 1 35px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.third{
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.noWidth {
  flex: 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <span ng-click="toggleBlue = !toggleBlue">TOGGLE BLUE BOX</span>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second" ng-class="{noWidth: toggleBlue}"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, after I removed the div with the classes .row .second it works without changing something else. Thanks!

Comment: @MrBuggy I would still make sure that any child element of an element that uses `display: flex` has `flex: 1 1 auto` or something similar. If you don't the browser has to use a bunch of weird back up scenarios of which may not work correctly cross browser (as you have noticed).

For more info here is a great tutorial of flexbox!
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yes, I use `flex: 1 1 auto;` in case of `flex: 1;` I changed it. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

added

```
.decrease {
   flex: 1 0;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand how your code must work is right... (

Comment: it should work like in the snippet... I remove the blue one and fill it with the red one...but on safari its like on the picture below the snippet, it removes the blue one but the red one doesn't fill it, it has the same width an the yellow also is than not in the end its behind the red one... Compare the snippet and the picture and you'll see it..